# Full page cropped video in HTML5 - no jquery

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

I'm trying to add a video in the background of my website. I want to do this without any javascript to optimize the loading time.
So far, I used this code:
HTML:

```
        <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" poster="img/video-poster.jpg" > 
          <img src="img/video-poster.jpg" alt=""/>
          <source type="video/mp4" src="video/video.mp4"/>
          <source type="video/ogg" src="video/video.ogv"/>
       </video>
```

CSS:

```
  #video_background { 
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px; 
      right: 0px; 
      min-width: 100%; 
      min-height: 100%; 
      width: auto; 
      height: auto; 
      z-index: -1000; 
      overflow: hidden
    }
```

The problem is that my video has a panoramic format (16/9) with black margins on top and bottom. Obviously I don't want them to appear on the screen. So with this code, the blacks margin appear on the bottom of the page.

How can I make sure the black margins are cropped and still have a responsive display?

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle? And also, jquery is cached in nearly everybody's browser already. As long you use one of the popular CDN's then there will be virtually no load time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There may be a better option out there but I find this to be an elegant solution in my eyes.

I gave the video `#video-background` a `scale(1.09)` which would zoom the video in ever so slightly to remove the borders.

I also added this to the `html` and `body` to disable the video from going under the fold. This is optional but you will have the bottom border without it.

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

The `css` for your video,

```
#video-background { 
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px; 
   right: 0px; 
   min-width: 100%; 
   min-height: 100%; 
   width: auto; 
   height: auto; 
   z-index: -1000; 
   overflow: hidden;
   transform: scale(1.09);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.09);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.09);
   -o-transform: scale(1.09);
}
```

Finally, here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/WQWqA/8/show/) to show how it looks. In the url, remove `/show` to see the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot itworks perfectly fine! Is there any way I can center the video vertically when the window size gets too small?

Comment: I can try to figure something out.